# How to Assign @csrf to a Variable As String and Decode on Runtime

Tags: php, csrf, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I am assigning HTML form to a variable so I can hold HTML and render it when I need, everything works fine but `@csrf` showing as a string on form while other already converted to HTML.

```php
$return .= '<form method="post" id="crud_form" action="'.route('post_crud_model_form').'">';    
$return .= "@csrf";
$return .= '<input type="hidden" id="input' . $data_id . '" value="' . $val . 
$return .= '<input type="text" id="text' . $data_id . '" value="ax1">';
$return .= '</form>';
```

[image]

Is there any better solution? I have to keep form in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csrf_field()` does just that:

```
$return .= '<form method="post" id="crud_form" action="'.route('post_crud_model_form').'">';    
$return .= csrf_field(); 
$return .= '<input type="hidden" id="input' . $data_id . '" value="' . $val . 
$return .= '<input type="text" id="text' . $data_id . '" value="ax1">';
$return .= '</form>';
```

Comment: but that is printing on the form    like this    chDGPydOu5j4okHClr3yeDtIt3jvjPYZxM2V3bKW

Comment: Sorry, in that case you need `csrf_field()` :)

Comment: Great. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: sure why not dear

Comment: 3 minutes wait required from stack

Comment: You can find my contact on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7894027/mozammil?tab=profile), but usually if you post your questions on here, I'd be around to take a look anyway. This also means that your questions could be helpful to somebody else :)